# Sending hex value to bluetooth device with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to send a specific hex value to a characteristic of a device through an iOS app.

I already successfully scan for devices, connect to a specific device, discovering services, discovering characteristics and pointing a specific one.

Here is my func to send data to my device.

```
func writeOutgoingValue(data: String){
      
    let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    
    if let myPeripheral = myPeripheral {
          
      if let rxCharacteristic = rxCharacteristic {
              
        myPeripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: rxCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
          }
      }
```

But this is indeed sending a utf8 value. How can I send an hex value ?

Thanks !

EDIT :

If anyone else is struggling with this, I resolved it like this :

```
  let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, ... ]
    
     myPeripheral.writeValue(Data(bytes), for: rxCharacteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
```

Comment: This isn't sending a "UTF8" value or a "hex" value since there aren't really any such things.  UTF8 is simply a way of mapping bytes to a character set.  `writeValue` sends the series of 8 bit bytes in the `Data` instance.  So, in this case you are sending the bytes that comprise the input string interpreted using the UTF8 encoding.  What are you trying to send to your peripheral.  A string like "Hello world" or a series of hex bytes like 0x02,0x22,0x33...  What is your input `data` to this function?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i’m a bit new to this, you’re absolutely right. The data I’m trying to send to the device looks like « 0110000b000102000166eb ». There are other simlar values but they are all 22 characters numbers/small letters. While normally using the Nrfconnect or BLE Scanner iOS app, I’d put this respectively in the « bytearray » or « hex » value and send it to the device and it’d work. I’m just trying to execute this action via a button press on an ios app. Thank you for helping !